# Which one to start with IonicFramework 2 or angularjs 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular

I am just getting started with ionicframework and I realized that it uses a lot of Angularjs 2. Iwatched a few videos of each. What is the best way to get started? Should I learn angularjs 2 to a certain degree before I move to ionicframework or is it ok to get started with ionicframe work and learn angularjs 2 as one goes along?

Thanks
UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried Ionic 2, but if it uses Angular 2 you should at least start with the quickstart & tour of heroes tutorial of Angular 2 so you will get the basics.

[Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

[Angular 2 Tour of heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using Ionic 2 and Angular 2 to create an app. Start off with Angular 2 because there is a lot to learn. Angular 2 is a lot different than JQuery or even Angular 1, and it can take getting used to. Ionic is pretty straightforward and easy to pick up on.

The [docs for Ionic 2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/) are clear, user-friendly, and much less intimidating than Angular 2 docs. So, I would recommend starting with Angular 2.

Comment: Thank you very much